# replace brackets by double inverted commas " " in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How to replace brackets {} by  double inverted commas"" in Notepad++

```
title={key players in the earth system},
author={Devid, Jhon A and SWAT, David J and Franks, Peter J},
journal={Current opinion in plant biology},
```

After replaced, it would be

```
title="key players in the earth system",
author="Devid, Jhon A and SWAT, David J and Franks, Peter J",
journal="Current opinion in plant biology",
```

Comment: Use Sublime instead for doing faster operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following find and replace all in regex mode:

**Find:**

```
\{(.*?)\}
```

**Replace:**

```
“$1”
```

Nothing magical here, though it should be noted that the regex pattern `.*?` uses a *lazy* dot.  The `?` tells the regex to stop upon hitting the *first* closing bracket.  If we used `.*` instead, the regex would consume everything until the very last closing bracket.

**Update:**

The above find and replace should be working, but as an alternative pattern you could try:

```
\{([^}]*)\}
```

## Demo

Comment: @SWAT Are you sure you were in regex mode when you did the find and replace?

Comment: yes, I am using the regular expression under search tab

Comment: Search tab?  You need to _replace_.  Do a find on my pattern and replace with what I have listed.

Comment: I just removed  ?  mark from the command line, Now it is only replacing the open bracket ( { ) and the close bracket is not replacing.

Comment: @SWAT Strange that the first pattern did not work in Notepad++; it worked in the demo (and would likely work in most programming languages).